# Как массиву присвоить другой массив

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

у меня есть переменная типа

```
const arr=[
{value:"ocean",label:"Ocean"},
{value:"ocean1",label:"Ocean1"}
{value:"ocean2",label:"Ocean2"}
]
```

у меня есть массив arr1=[1,2,3,4] к примеру
как мне передать этот массив в arr?(чтоб value,label присвоились эти числа )?

пробовал так `const arr={value:arr1,label:arr1}`
и так `const arr=[{value:arr1,label:arr1}]` но это не то

Comment: какой ожидаемый вывод?

Comment: просто я пытаюсь сделать на примере multiselect и в options нужно передать тип arr:{value,label}[] а если я  просто передаю массив то пишет each child in a list should have a unique key prop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const arr = arr1.map((element) => ({value: element, label: element}))
```

А можно сразу в реакт-компоненте без создания промежуточной переменной.

```
{arr.map((value) => <Children key={value} value={value} />}
```